# Create a mapping system from factor variable to numeric in R

Tags: r

I have an education column that consists of a number of strings.  These are the levels of the factor variable.

```
 [1] "NIU or no schooling"                                 "NIU"                                                
 [3] "None or preschool"                                   "Grades 1, 2, 3, or 4"                               
 [5] "Grade 1"                                             "Grade 2"                                            
 [7] "Grade 3"                                             "Grade 4"                                            
 [9] "Grades 5 or 6"                                       "Grade 5"                                            
[11] "Grade 6"                                             "Grades 7 or 8"                                      
[13] "Grade 7"                                             "Grade 8"                                            
[15] "Grade 9"                                             "Grade 10"                                           
[17] "Grade 11"                                            "Grade 12"                                           
[19] "12th grade, no diploma"                              "12th grade, diploma unclear"                        
[21] "High school diploma or equivalent"                   "1 year of college"                                  
[23] "Some college but no degree"                          "2 years of college"                                 
[25] "Associate's degree, occupational/vocational program" "Associate's degree, academic program"               
[27] "3 years of college"                                  "4 years of college"                                 
[29] "Bachelor's degree"                                   "5+ years of college"                                
[31] "5 years of college"                                  "6+ years of college"                                
[33] "Master's degree"                                     "Professional school degree"                         
[35] "Doctorate degree"                                    "Missing/Unknown"
```

I want to convert this factor variable into a numeric such that Grade 1 --> 1, Grade 2 --> 2, and in-between grades are simply the average between any listed grade.

I can do this manually, but it would require 35 individual commands.  Is there an easier way in R to create a mapping system between the factor?

Comment: How do you intend to handle grades 5 or 6? There may need to be a rather extensive rule set to achieve your goal.

Comment: As I mentioned,  I want to take the average of in-between grades.  So 5 or 6 --> 5.5  1, 2, 3 or 4 would be 2.5

Comment: Are you trying to avoid manually creating the mapping or are you just trying to keep the code simple? Keeping the code simple could be accomplished with a `data.frame` that has the mapping from the factor to the numeric or with a custom function use `switch`. Getting R to construct the mapping automatically would be a lot more work than making the mapping manually.

Comment: What grade is `"Doctorate degree"`?

Comment: Probably 21.  I can fiddle with the actual numerical mapping later, but it looks like there isn't a straightforward way to do this automatically.  I was thinking of some Regex action, but I think it's easier to just use recode.

Comment: You can start with `sapply(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+"), function(.x) mean(as.numeric(.x),na.rm=T))` and delete any unnecessary entries.

Comment: One tangential question.  I'm trying to manually record items with apostrophes and it keeps throwing an "unexpected symbol" issue, even after escaping.  `cps08$educ2 <- recode(cps08$educ,"'Master\'s Degree' = 19")`  What seems to be the problem?

Comment: But you don't have to escape the apostrophes. You do not have nested quotes. Not sure why your string is wrapped in double and single quotes. `"'Master's'"` does not match your example.